# How to kill other application Android

Tags: android

How can one app kills other apps in android? I am developing a Parental control application which gonna block other apps from running same as [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) and [Android Parental Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlobe.smartappcloud.android.parentalcontrol) are doing. These apps require password on opening/launching of any locked application, If password is not correct then they kill that application.
I have few questions:

1. How these apps are monitoring other application launches? (by contentiously reading activity manager? from background service)
2. How these apps kill other application although android OS doesn't allow it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

NOTE: PLEASE DON'T START YOUR ANSWERS WITH **"ITS NOT POSSIBLE IN ANDROID"**, I ALREADY MENTIONED APPS WHICH HAVE ACHIEVED IT.

Comment: u mean whatever apps are installed in android phone iu wanna watch that?

Comment: yes, Please don't say that its not possible in android, Because a lots of parental control applications are doing that.

Comment: hehe i m not saying that , but would like to answer this question...u wanna do this for apps ? or browser contents also?

Comment: Right now, i wanna do it for apps, Thank You @Monica

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028357/lock-other-apps-while-my-application-runs

Comment: @Monica looking forward for your answer :) please let me know if you have any idea to do it.

Comment: @AhmadRaza below answer wil help you na

Comment: @Monica its not working for me :-(

Comment: cool i need to give a try today thn i will getback with answer

Comment: @Monica I will wait for your answer :) Thank You!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, how?

Comment: @TahaYusuf: Unfortunately. i haven't get any solution yet!

Comment: vote up for the note :D

Comment: Do you solve this problem ?

Comment: @Menna-AllahSami: Killing other apps isn't possible in android anymore. But you can monitor other apps by reading activity logs.

Comment: Okay so how application such as AppLock works ?

Comment: All those apps, They don't kill other applications. They just launch HomeScreen(HomeScreen is also an app, when they launch it, the current visible application go to hidden state)

Comment: This is how you can launch home screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756835/how-to-launch-home-screen-programmatically-in-android (Have Fun)

Answer (score 3):

There are certain answers on this topic stack-overflow already, like

1. [Block Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018961/block-applications)
2. [How to Lock(Block) an android application from starting / How to stop an android application (service) from starting at boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700262/how-to-lockblock-an-android-application-from-starting-how-to-stop-an-android)
3. [Kill another application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-in-android)

That should be of some help.
Android doesn't allow apps to interfere with other apps easily,I don't think there is a clean way to do this without hacking into launch process or without changing the privileges your app has.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill any process this in pre 2.2 version of OS unless your app has got root access. Post 2.2 You can only stop back ground processes or services of other apps but you cannot stop the Activity windows.